# Configuring an Azure Web Role Startup Task from a ServiceConfiguration file

Tags: azure, startup, azure-web-roles

I have an azure `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file that has a number of startup tasks. One of these tasks I only want to run for a specific environment. I don't seem to be able to run startup tasks in a `ServiceConfiguration-[Environment].cscfg` file. Is it possible to only run a startup task for a given environment?

Comment: What's the nature of the environment specific item? Sometimes start-up tasks get used for things that should almost be part of the deployment/provisioning stage.

Comment: It is the installer that comes in the new relic monitoring package.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement conditional per environment startup tasks is to add service configuration files per environment to your .ccproj Visual studio project file and to xcopy from environment to  ServiceDefinition.csdef on a pre-build event.  This will also allow you to have different size instances per environment as well, if you want to have Xtra-small servers in Dev/QA and larger size in Prod.

Check out my blog on instructions for how to... It has extra stuff in there, but covers adding of the other environment .csdef files and xcopying them: http://blog.paraleap.com/post/2011/09/13/Managing-environments-in-a-distributed-Azure-or-other-cloud-based-NET-solution

Comment: the start-ups are declared in the csdef, not the cscfg. But the transformation route is another solid possibility. :)

Comment: Thanks for the catch Brent... going on 2hrs of sleep today :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that's helps. There's two options..

1) create two solutions with linked source files where one has the csdef with the command, the other does not. Ugly, not sure I'd actually recommend this one. 
2) wrap your installer in such a way that you can control when the script is executed. Either via some external variable, or type of controllable parameter.